# Google sheets, get the last row number of repeated value

Tags: google-sheets

I have column like so

```
Mike
Fred
Mike
Andy
Mike
```

I want to return to me the last row number where the column = `Mike`. So in this case the output should be `5`

I've think its combination of `max` `filter` `row` functions but need help on putting it together. Or maybe it could be done another way.

This is my best attempt so far:
`= ROW (FILTER(A1:A, ROW(A1:A) =MAX( FILTER( ROW(A1:A) , ("Mike")))) )`

Comment: Most the row number come from the range or the sheet?

Comment: it should come from the range

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
=max(arrayformula(if(A1:A5="Mike", row(A1:A5), 0)))
```

Comment: Better is to write: `=max(arrayformula(if(A1:A5="Mike", row(A:A), 0)))`

Comment: Why would that better? I would argue that the range argument to the IF condition and to the ROW function should be exactly the same, for clarity's sake.

Comment: Have you tried that? What happens if you do this: =max(arrayformula(if(C14:C18="Mike", row(C14:C18), 0)))?

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that it would return absolute vs. relative row numbers depending on the form of range argument. Is this documented somewhere? Certainly not in ROW()'s help.

Comment: Since you found there is actually a glitch in the formula, I believe you could update your answer following @JacobJanTuinstra comment.

Comment: Hi @marikamitsos, I considered that decided against it because the OP does not precise in the question whether he wants relative or absolute numbering. If the question would be made more precise, I can make my answer more precise too.