# Find the last instance of multiple values

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula

I really need some help with this.

I need to search for the value of A2: B2 in another tab in google sheets and it needs to return the row number of last occurrence/entry of the values in A2: B2 in Column C2.

My case is similar to this [Finding Last Instance](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/105206/google-sheets-get-the-last-row-number-of-repeated-value?rq=1) but two lookup value.

**This is what in Sheet1.**

[image]

**This is what in sheet2.**

[image]

Tried this formula:
*=if(isblank(A2),"--",max(filter(row(Sheet2),Sheet2=A2)))*

The formula is working but it is only for 1 value which is in A2.

So for example, since I am looking for last instance of A2: B2 in Sheet2, it should return the row number **20**

I really want to share a sample sheet, but the company restrictions do not allow me to do so.

Recommendations and advice will be truly appreciated. And thank you in advance as well.

Comment: Welcome. Please show us what you mean. I am personally kind of lost with just the word explaining. Also, write couple of the formulas you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the following formula:

```
=QUERY( 
     ARRAY_CONSTRAIN( 
       SORTN({Sheet2!B2:B26&Sheet2!C2:C26, row(Sheet2!A2:A26),Sheet2!A2:A26},2,3,3,0),6,3), 
        "select Col2")
```

In our formula we create a virtual column `Sheet2!B2:B26&Sheet2!C2:C26` by joining 
the two columns together, thus creating unique values.
We also use an extra column `row(Sheet2!A2:A26)` in order to return the corresponding rows values. The column we use makes no difference as long as it is in the range of 2-26.

[image]

Functions used:

- [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)
- [`ARRAY_CONSTRAIN`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3267036)
- [`SORTN`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7354624)
- [`ROW`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093316)

Comment: Great. *"I really want to share a sample sheet, but the company restrictions do not allow me to do so."*. Please read how to and [share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) so as you can be easier helped. You can prepare a new file. And it doesn't even be from the office. Demo sheets save masses of time to ones trying to help you. Have a nice weekend.

Comment: If still in trouble, **do share a demo sheet as [explained before](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/142758/find-the-last-instance-of-multiple-values/142787?noredirect=1#comment130260_142787)**.

Comment: Hi, it's working fine. However, if the lookup file is unsorted, it's not returning the right results.