# How to get the last instance with connecting criteria in google sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have a similar case with this. [Getting the last instance](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/142758/find-the-last-instance-of-multiple-values/142871#142871)

However, my look-up range is unsorted. Is there any way to do this?
I have a formula for the first instance.

```
=ROW(INDEX(INDIRECT($C$2),MATCH(1,($A4=indirect($C$2))*($B4=indirect($D$2)),0)))
```

But I need to work for the last instance. I've been trying for days but I could not seem to do it.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. It's not clear how this question relates to the referred question. Please add more details including a sample input data and the expected result.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google sheets, get the last row number of repeated value](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/105206/google-sheets-get-the-last-row-number-of-repeated-value)